# Invalid procedure call or argument when using collection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection inside `Init` method that is created on Excel open event:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const Mname As String = "MyPopUpMenu"
Public NavigatorType As Variant
Public NavigatorUrl As New Collection

Sub Init()
    NavigatorType = "Series" ' Set default url type
    Set NavigatorUrl = New Collection
    NavigatorUrl.Add "https://www.series.com", "Series"
    NavigatorUrl.Add "https://www.lists.com", "Lists"
    NavigatorUrl.Add "https://www.datatypes.com", "Datatypes"
    NavigatorUrl.Add "https://www.expressions.com", "Expressions"
End Sub
```

When I click on ActiveX button, I am calling `openNavigatorUrl`:

`btnFindSeries_MouseDown` method is inside sheet

```
Public Sub btnFindSeries_MouseDown(ByVal button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    If button = 1 Then
        openNavigatorUrl
    ElseIf button = 2 Then
        CreatePopUpMenu
    End If
End Sub
```

openNavigatorUrl method:

```
Sub openNavigatorUrl()
    MsgBox NavigatorUrl(NavigatorType) // getting error here
End Sub
```

I am not sure what is wrong here? I am getting erro: `Invalid procedure call or argument`

Comment: Are `NavigatorUrl` and `NavigatorType` defined as global?

Comment: @FunThomas yes both are global

Comment: @KostasK. I have declared it as Variant

Comment: @KostasK. I tried with String as well. The issue I guess is accessing `NavigatorUrl(NavigatorType)`. May be it is looking for method Sub instead of accessing the key

Comment: I believe a dictionary would be more appropriate for your solution than a collection. Good luck.

Comment: @KostasK. Dictinary is not being recognised. I tried already

Comment: @KostasK. I fixed it by updating `navigatorUrl.Add "https://www.series.com", Key:="Series"` using `Key` but there is one more issue

Comment: NavigatorType = "Series" is getting emptied some how

Comment: I think you cant retrieve the key in a collection. Only in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating with `Key` like this:

```
navigatorUrl.Add "https://www.series.com", Key:="Series"
navigatorUrl.Add "https://www.lists.com", Key:="Lists"
navigatorUrl.Add "https://www.datatypes.com", Key:="Datatypes"
navigatorUrl.Add "https://www.expressions.com", Key:="Expressions"
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the solution, it's exactly the same as in your original code, just using a different syntax.

Comment: @FunThomas Some how its recognizing this code. May be API is updated

Comment: Both ways are fine and do exactly the same, filling a collection with 4 entries. The first parameter is the value, the second is the key. You may used named parameter in VBA (as you did in your answer), but that doesn't change anything. I strongly assume that when you got your error, `NavigatorType` was holding an invalid value.

Comment: No I tried to hardcoded value instead of `NavigatorType` but still was not able to access the key